# Get a single document in firestore with a variable as parameter does not work

Tags: javascript, reactjs, database, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am currently trying to get one document from my firebase/firestore. Using the following code.

```
 const docRef = doc(firestore, 'users', "customidxyz");

      const docSnap = await getDoc(docRef);
      console.log(docSnap.data()); // => gives me excpected output
```

That works as expected, but if I change the code to the following:

```
const docRef = doc(firestore, 'users', userData.uid);

      const docSnap = await getDoc(docRef);
      console.log(docSnap.data()); => logs undefined
```

I only receive an undefined log. I checked and am very sure that the value in userData.uid is the exact same as the hardcoded value.

I hope you someone could help me.

thank you

I checked that the hardcoded value is the same one as the value in the variable.

Comment: "I checked and am very sure that the value in userData.uid is the exact same as the hardcoded value." Can you ensure that is the case in the code itself? For example, `console.log(userData.uid)` right before you use the value, or even better `if (userData.uid === "customidxyz") { query code here }`.